# What word would be used to describe someone who has grown up with something?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that could be used to describe someone as being comfortable with something (in this case technology) due to having grown up in a world with it. I know the term digital-native is thrown around a lot but am looking for something akin to this but in a single word.

I've also thought along the lines of 'familiar' but didn't quite seem to fit. Anyone else got any better ideas?

Comment: I grew up on tech.

Comment: I take it *technology* specifically means ***digital** technology* to you (virtually everyone alive today grew up with technology far more advanced than existed when their *parents* were young). But it's worth noting that although there was virtually no such thing as digital technology when I was growing up back in the 50s/60s, I'd still tend to say it's ***second nature*** to me today. Simply because I started using such technology ***a long time ago***, so I'm really used to it (even though it's sometimes a struggle to keep up these days! :)

Comment: Tech-savvy.  As another example: Farm-savvy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon there are more fitting words than these, but I'll carry on.

Without a specific reference to having *grown up* with something, you can be (or become) ***accustomed*** to [technology].

If [technology] pervaded your childhood to the extent that it is everywhere and all-around and is *second nature* to you, it has become accepted and incorporated into life, you can be said to have been [***indoctrinated***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/indoctrinated) into technology.  The word basically means "brainwashed" or "conditioned" - but can be toyed with.

[***Conditioned***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conditioned) might be worth a quick mention because it refers to "having a significant influence on or determine the manner or outcome of something."

Comment: I feel this answer is still slightly off-the-mark and could be superseded.  Who else got what?

Comment: There's something about "native" that has the right ring to it, about being comfortable with something without even thinking about it--like growing up in the city vs. the country (and vv.). Inherent.  Tech-native?

Answer (score -1):

I would say the best fit single word is:

***[Technophile](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/technophile)***

> A person who is enthusiastic about new technology.

(Oxford)

Comment: Ah the fun of a perfectly fine (perhaps the best possible) answer getting down-voted is always... fun.

Comment: I'm over 60, and didn't grow up with digital technology, but I'm definitely a *technophile*. Come to that, I know several people under 25 who *aren't* particularly interested in it. That's to say I ***don't*** think this is a "perfectly fine answer" to the specific question as posed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Great good for you. I hope your ego benefited where my ELU score ranking didn't :)